# Edit user - Check what is selected in "list" field

Tags: entities, users

On user edit page, i have a "list" field where user can choose is it male or female.

I need to check whether user choosed Male or Female..

Is it possible to check what user have choosen?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide more info about the site setup, Drupal version, which plugins did you use to add the field and what for do you want to use the check based on gender.

Comment: Drupal 7.19 . No plugins for fields.. Just from drupal core... I want to display icon based on gender..

Comment: Do you want to check client side or server side?

Comment: Well what's better? I really dont know...

Comment: I made it with strstr function. I know what user can select so i just check what he selected...